# How to place an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

I have taken the following sentence from this [website](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/individually#YqGRqqd2x1Kgr273.99).

> The Jews were also enjoined to confess their sins ***individually*** to God, and in certain cases to man.

We all know that adverb modifies verb, adjective, and another adverb. But in above sentence, the adverb "individually" sits between two nouns. Is this correct? I think "individually" modifies the infinitive "confess". If so, can I move the adverb beside the infinitive?

> The Jews were also enjoined to confess ***individually*** their sins  to God, and in certain cases to man.

If the adverb "individually" modifies the noun "sins" (confessing their sins one-by-one) as mentioned by @user3169, can I rephrase the sentence to

> The Jews were also enjoined to confess their ***individual sins***  to God, and in certain cases to man.

If not, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adverb can modify the entire predicate.

> He removed the lid of the paint can carefully.

It could appear before "removed"

> He carefully removed...

or after it, as a parenthetic, for special emphasis

> He removed, carefully, the lid...

or at the end of the phrase, as shown at the top.

If I wanted to make clear that individual sins should be confessed, I'd use the adjective **individual** rather than rely upon placement of the adverb.

**The Jews were enjoined to confess their *individual* sins.**

It's not clear in any case what "confess their sins individually" means.  Not as a congregation, but one person at a time, standing before the congregation? Or sin by sin? Additional context would be needed.

Comment: Here is additional context "Among the Jews it was ordered that on the Day of Atonement the high priest should make confession of sins in the name of the whole people, and the day is still kept by the Jews with fasting and confession of sins. The Jews were also enjoined to confess their sins individually to God, and in certain cases to man." http://encyclopedia.jrank.org/COM_COR/CONFESSION_Lat_confessio_from_c.html

Comment: In that case, in light of "in the name of the whole people", I'd interpret **individually** to mean individual persons not individual sins.

Comment: I think this must be the answer "The Jews were also enjoined individually to confess their sins to God, and in certain cases to man." Am I right? As it is adverb modifier it must be placed near the word that modifies.

Comment: The grammar doesn't care which of the valid places it goes. Clarity demands that it be placed where it does not result in an ambiguity.   It could go at the head of the sentence. "*Individually* the Jews were enjoined..." or before or after "enjoined" ... "The Jews were *individually* enjoined..." or "The Jews were enjoined *individually*". If it appears after "sins" "....their sins *individually*" or "their sins to God *individually*" it might be thought to modify "sins".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a matter of interpretation, but I would put it this way.

> The Jews were also enjoined to confess their **sins individually** to God, and in certain cases to man.

Here "individually" modifies "sins" (confess their sins one-by-one).

> **The Jews** were also enjoined to **confess individually** their sins to God, and in certain cases to man.

Here "individually" modifies "confess" (each of the Jews confess).

Comment: Is it possible to rephrase the first sentence to "The Jews were also enjoined to confess their "individual" sins to God, and in certain cases to man"? Here I have modified adverb to adjective.

Comment: Looks good to me. It is clearer this way. In the same way, you could write (with different meaning) "*Individual* Jews were also enjoined to confess their sins to God, and in certain cases to man."